# Find the value of sum $\forall\:\:\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

> Evaluate the sum $\forall\:\:\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^{n+1}-1}{n(n+1)}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\beta}\right)$$

I rewrote this as $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{\alpha^{n+1}-1}{n}-\frac{\alpha^{n+1}-1}{n+1}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\beta}\right)\right)$$ But this is not helping me. I also expanded the sin by its Taylor Series, but it got even more complicated. I then tried wolframaplha, but it does not recognize it as a problem. It doesn't read it as a problem. How should I proceed from here$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

## Update

With the helpful hints I got, I managed to proceed as follows
$$\frac{\partial^2S}{\partial\alpha^2}=\mathfrak{J}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\alpha\cdot e^{\frac{i\pi}{\beta}})^n\right)$$
Now this is just a normal Geometric Progression. But after this what should I do$?$ How to separate the imaginary part$?$ And, I don't think I'm equipped enough to integrate the resultant expression. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about writing $\sin(n\pi/\beta)$ as the imaginary part of $\exp(in\pi/\beta)$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe i haven't tried that

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I notice that differentiating the terms twice in $\alpha$ gives $\alpha^{n-1}\sin(n\pi/\beta)$. That might be a starting point?

Comment: That is to say, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\alpha^2}S = \sum_{n\ge1} \alpha^{n-1}\sin(n\pi/\beta)$ (assuming it's well-behaved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier: put $z=e^{\pm i\pi/\beta}$ and $z=\alpha e^{\pm i\pi/\beta}$ into $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}=z+(1-z)\log(1-z)\qquad(|z|\leqslant 1)$$

Comment: Can you pls elaborate

Comment: How did log come into picture

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad: Do you know $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}n=-\log(1-z)$?

Comment: no i dont ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad: That series is a result of integration of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n-1}=1/(1-z)$, or just an example of [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Examples). Take its consequences $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n+1}}{n}=z\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}=-z\log(1-z),\\\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}=-z-\log(1-z),$$ and subtract the latter from the former (traces of this are seen in your own approach).

Comment: Okk I understood...but what should I do after this...as I have to take only the imaginary part

Comment: And one more thing...how is log defined for complex numbers ...I've not studied complex logarithms yet

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad: I think it's time to. The result (for $|\alpha|<1$), expressed in terms of real numbers (only), $S=f(\alpha,\pi/\beta)-\lim\limits_{r\to1^-}f(r,\pi/\beta)$, where $$f(r,\phi)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{r^{n+1}\sin n\phi}{n(n+1)}=(r-\cos\phi)\arctan\frac{r\sin\phi}{1-r\cos\phi}-\frac{\sin\phi}2\log(1-2r\cos\phi+r^2),$$ doesn't look very pleasant (although the limit does). And, in my opinion, this is *much* harder to obtain using real-only methods.

Comment: I think this question isn't meant for me...anyways you can write the full answer using your method (if u wish) for the future readers:)