# Follow up query to a MSE question of summation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms

> Evaluate the sum $\forall\:\:\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^{n+1}-1}{n(n+1)}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\beta}\right)$$

This is a follow up query to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653128/find-the-value-of-sum-forall-alpha-beta-in-mathbbr/4653143#4653143)

The answer given there was partial and I couldn't understand that. The answer was

Easier: put $z=e^{\pm i\pi/\beta}$ and $z=\alpha e^{\pm i\pi/\beta}$ into $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}=z+(1-z)\log(1-z)\qquad(|z|\leqslant 1)$$

---

My question is what to do after this$?$ How to seperate the real and imaginary parts$?$ And how can a complex number inside a logarithmic function $?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't know how to work with complex logarithms, you're probably not at a level to be using this hint anyway (you need to know at least the basics of complex analysis). Equivalence of the hint with your question upon taking imaginary parts follows immediately from Euler's identity.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen can you provide me with a method which is suitable for a high schooler...or methods which are not so above high school?